# Xcode compiler error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have an app that has two view controllers the first view controller has 3 buttons one of those buttons pushes to the next view controller.

I keep getting this error

```
return uiapplicationmain(argc argv nil nsstringfromclass( appdelegate class)
```

The only files I have are:

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
ViewController.h
ViewController.m
```

I have only been adding things through the Main.storyboard.

Comment: What error? You haven't posted any error.

Comment: And please see this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for stray connections in the buttons where one button isn't supposed to be linked to an outlet or action. To do that, go to the storyboard, and for every button, click the rightmost tab in the inspector (right menu) and check for your connections.

Comment: I clicked all the buttons and they all just have "Triggered Suegues: action, View Controller Push" and when I click the line to check and see which button goes to which View Controller it has the correct button.

Comment: @isabella this usually happens when there is something wrong with the storyboard. Just to make sure, is the app crashing immediately?